# Default argument of generic type, instantiated to int is 'null' according to Intellisense

Tags: generics, intellisense, default, arguments, value-type

Out of curiosity, is the following a bug or intended behavior? It seems IMHO strange that the default argument of an integer parameter is `null`.

[image: Intellisense says (int arg = null)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my computer, VS Professional 2010, targeting .Net 4.0, it has the correct information `int arg = Default(T)`. So, I suppose you are not going crazy :)

Comment: Well technically, shouldn't default(int) = 0, or at least default(int)?

Comment: @fowl Not sure I follow. The default for int is 0, but that is not what intellisense, at least for my version of VS, shows.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was pointing out - the flaw/gap in intellisense. Everywhere else when using a method with generic type parameters intellisense fills in the actual type, except in this case where it uses "T", even when that isn't the name of a real type parameter!

Answer (score 1):

This could be your IDE displaying it improperly; if the code compiles properly, you might want to print the argument in that function, to ensure that you're getting the default value that you expect.

I would be willing to bet that it is functioning as intended.